# Counting with Replacement Every k Turns

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

The problem is as follows: You have `n` types of items and you want to select `l` of them (order matters). You can resample items of a type only if there are `k` other items selected since the last time you selected that item. Count the total number of sequences of items you can form. If this is confusing, the following example will clear things up:

Say `n = 5`, `l = 6`, and `k = 3`.

The answer is `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 2 * 2`. 
On the first turn we can choose any of the 5 items. On the second, third and fourth turns again we can choose any of the `4`, `3`, and `2` remaining items. Then, on the fifth turn we can choose `1`, but also `5` again because there were 3 other items selected since the last it was picked, and so on. So the total count is `480`.

Here's a naive algorithm to solve this:

```
def differentPlaylists(n, k, l):
    ans, choices = 1, n
    while l > 0:
        ans = (ans * choices) % 1000000007
        choices -= 1
        k, l = k - 1, l - 1
        if k < 0: choices += 1
    return ans
```

This works, but it's too slow. I can't figure out how I could produce an algorithm that solves this problem in less than `l` multiply ops.

Can someone help me figure out how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need only a remainder of the exact number. The answer is:
`(n! / (n-k)! * (n-k)^(l-k)) % M = 
(((n! / (n-k)!) % M) * ((n-k)^(l-k) % M)) % M`.

You don't need a loop to find `(n-k)^(l-k) % M`, you can use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that works in `O(log(l-k))`. If `k` is small enough it will make overall computation significantly faster because the first factorial part of this formula is calculated in `O(k)` in your solution. As a result the complexity is `O(log(l-k)) + O(k)` instead of `O(l)` in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying really hard to figure out how I could optimize the combinatorial argument that I couldn't see the optimization required was actually in the exponentiation. Here's a great article on computing exponents modulo m: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/28/efficient-modular-exponentiation-algorithms